# How much are Galleons, Sickles and Knuts worth in the real world?

Tags: harry-potter

By the way, Galleons, Sickles and Knuts are the currency of the Harry Potter World. How much are they each worth in $ and £ in the real world?  Also, are there different currencies for different countries?

## Edit:

looking at the right hand sign, my question

> Also, are there different currencies for different countries?

is a duplicate. Sorry!

Comment: In the "real world" they're not worth anything because they don't exist. Perhaps you meant what the exchange rate would be between wizarding and muggle currency in the Harry Potter universe?

Comment: Correct @ApproachingDarknessFish

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish - dunno, if someone somehow had some of those to try to spend - I seem to recall a mention of "great gold coins the size of hubcaps" which someone might be interested in acquiring, not to mention the value of silver.. and even copper.  Metal value should still exist, even if the currency-as-currency isn't recognized and therefore no "real world" exchange rate to be found.